# 「window.location.href」と「location.href」について

Tags: javascript

**両者の違いを知りたい**

---

**Q1.「location.href」よりも「window.location.href」と書いた方が良いケースはある？**
・グローバルオブジェクトがwindowではない所からのリンクって例えばどんな時ですか？
・スマホのブラウザからのアクセスも、グローバルオブジェクトはwindow？

---

**Q2.グローバルオブジェクト対象について**
・例えば、「aサイトからbサイトへ遷移」した場合、「location.href」のグローバルオブジェクトは「aサイト」「bサイト」の何れが対象？
・そもそも両者のグローバルオブジェクトが異なっていること自体が有り得ない？？

---

**Q3.window以外のグローバルオブジェクトについて**
・例えば、Node.js経由で表示しているブラウザのグローバルオブジェクトはwindowですか？
・Node.jsの中のグローバルオブジェクトだけがglobal？

Comment: 「Node.js経由で表示しているブラウザ」とはどういう状況なんでしょうか? HTTPサーバがNode.jsで、クライアントがブラウザ?

Comment: 「Node.js」自体が良く分かっていないのですが、「Node.js」で生成しているサイトからアクセスがあったらという意味で質問しました。サーバ側だけがNode.jsなので、生成されているサイトはクライアント？　ブラウザなのでグローバルオブジェクトはwindow？？　Node.jsでWebサイトを生成するということがどういうことなのかよく分かっていません

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. あります。

スコープ上に `window.location` 以外の変数 `location` が存在する場合があります。

```
function foo(...) {
  let location = 'Tokyo';
  // location と window.location は違う。
  ..
}
```

また、同名のローカル変数がない場合でも `window.location` と書いた場合と `location` と書いた場合でパフォーマンスが違うという話も聞いたことがあります。

> グローバルオブジェクトがwindowではない所からのリンクって例えばどんな時ですか？

質問の意味わかりません。

> スマホのブラウザからのアクセスも、グローバルオブジェクトはwindow？

スマートフォンかどうかに関わらず、ウェブブラウザ環境でのメインスレッドのグローバルオブジェクトは `window` です。

ただし、ブラウザ環境でもワーカー内は `self` がグローバルオブジェクトになります。

A2. `window` グローバルオブジェクトは、ページ毎に異なるものが用意されます。ページA内のスクリプトから見える `window` と、ページB内のスクリプトから見える `window` は、別のものです。

(厳密にはブラウジングコンテキスト毎で、IFRAMEを持っているドキュメントとそのIFRAME内のドキュメントは別の `window` を持ちます)

A3. Node.js の JavaScript 実行環境とブラウザの JavaScript 実行環境は何も関係がありません。Node.js ではいつでも `global`、ブラウザ内ではいつでも `window` `self` などです。

Comment: 「location.href」のグローバルオブジェクトを考える際、リンク元は関係ないのですね。勘違いしていました